# Font-face SVG issues on ipad

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to use font-face for my google fonts, however I have recentley discovered the iPad can't read the WOFF format, only SVG.

Here is my declaration direct from google, but as you can see it's only WOFF, how can I encorporate SVG use?

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:700;
    src:local('Yanone Kaffeesatz Bold'),local('YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold'),url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/yanonekaffeesatz/v2/We_iSDqttE3etzfdfhuPRbJjSLMfVFmTspsxH0yGxjj3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the font-face generator at font squirrel. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator . It's the best tool I've found for doing anything to do with font-face by a long way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the mime-type on the server to serve svg. e.g. `image/svg+xml`

I would definitely follow Rich Bradshaw's advice to use fontsquirrel to generate your css and fonts for you though also.